# I want help in creating DynamoDB table using CloudFormation template

Tags: yaml, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I need a help in creating DynamoDB table using CloudFormation template.

Table name: oeautomator-team-config
Table Schema:

active - Boolean
devResolverGroups - List
excludeAgingList - Boolean
excludeNoncontrollableList - Boolean
excludeReroutedList - Boolean
fleetId - String
managerLogin - String
metricsDashboardLinks - Map
orgName - String
simFolderId - String
supportResolverGroups - List
teamName - String

Primary Partition key - teamName (String)

I formed a template

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  oeautomatorteamconfigTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: oeautomator-team-config
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: "teamName"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: "teamName"
          KeyType: "HASH"
      TimeToLiveSpecification:
        AttributeName: "ExpirationTime"
        Enabled: true
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: "5"
        WriteCapacityUnits: "5"
    DependsOn:
      - DynamoDBQueryPolicy
  DynamoDBQueryPolicy:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Policy"
    Properties:
      PolicyName: DynamoDBQueryPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action: "dynamodb:Query"
            Resource: "*"
      Roles:
        - Ref: "oeautomatorteamconfigTableQueryRole"

  oeautomatorteamconfigTableQueryRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "dynamodb.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Path: "/"
```

But not sure how to define the rest of all columns.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try it on your own first: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html If you encounter any problems then you can ask for help.

Comment: @RobertKossendey - I edited the question by template I've formed, but not sure how to define the rest of the attributes (table schema columns). Could you guide me how to define them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to specify the rest of the attributes. Dynamo is by definition [schemaless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.CreateTable.html#SQLtoNoSQL.CreateTable.DynamoDB), apart from hash and range key.